# Upgrade OpenCart in svn

Tags: svn, diff, upgrade, patch, opencart

I based my current OpenCart instalation on **v1.5.2.1** (let's call this **Orig_V1**).

I then heavily modified it and committed it in my SVN repository (let's call this **Mod_V1**, SVN rev: r1).

Now I want to upgrade it into **v1.5.4.1** (let's call this **Orig_V2**) and keep the modifications I had on **Mod_V1** (let's call this **Mod_V2**).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a merge and compare software to compare yours to the new upgrade. There are plenty of open source around. Try here.

http://www.noupe.com/tools/25-useful-document-and-file-comparison-tools.html

Winmerge is a good one. I use Notepad ++ with compare add-on. I need to do the same thing myself eventually!

Comment: It was a little more hands-on work but worth it in the end. I also used the new github OpenCart repository as a base and I can now go upstream easily. I did use N++ compare as well! :)